# Adding a comment to existing XML File using Python 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, python-3.4

i have following XML File:

```
<xml_connection_file xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mcf.xsd">
  <version> 1.0.0 </version>
  <connection_group>
    <id> 1 </id>
    <connected_to>
      <part>
        <base> A </base>
      </part>
      <part>
        <base> B </base>
      </part>
    </connected_to>
  </connection_group>
</xml_connection_file>
```

i wish to add a comment in the main node(xml_connection_file). i have written following code in python3 but the error is appearing saying  `'lxml.etree._ElementTree'` has no attribute `'insert'`.

```
from lxml import etree
from ansa import utils

my_selected_file = utils.SelectOpenFile(0, 'xml files (*.mcf)')

tree = etree.parse(my_selected_file[0])

comment = etree.Comment('my comments')
tree.insert(1,comment)

tree.write('new_file.mcf')
```

Can anyone can tell me what am i doing wrong? thanks in advane!

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import etree
from ansa import utils

my_selected_file = utils.SelectOpenFile(0, 'xml files (*.xml)')

tree = etree.parse(my_selected_file[0])
mainnode = tree.getroot()
comm = etree.Comment('--the filename--')
mainnode.insert(1, comm)
tree.write('output.xml')
```

I had not extracted the `Element` of xml file earlier and applied `insert` in the `tree`. Now, i have extracted `Element` (main node) using `getroot()` and inserted the comment using `insert` in this `Element`

Comment: Please do not leave code-only answers, add explanations to your answer.